# Is $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ an injective module over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I will use Baer's criterion. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, we have that every ideal $I$ is generated by some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$; hence, $(a) = I$. We have a hom from $I$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, let that hom be $\phi: I \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Let, $[k]_{2} = \phi(a)$. If $k = 0$, then $\phi$ is the trivial module hom which means we can trivially extend it by $\psi:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ where $\psi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. The other case is $\phi(a) = [1]_{2}$, which means, $\phi(ra) = [r]_{2}$. So we define, $\psi:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ where $\psi(r) = \phi(ra) = [r]_{2}$. We have that,

$$\psi(r_1 + r_2) = [r_1 + r_2]_{2} = [r_1]_{2} + [r_2]_{2} = \psi(r_1) + \psi(r_2). $$

So by Baer's criterion, $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is injective over $\mathbb{Z}$ as a module, but I have been told that this is not a true statement, so what is wrong with my proof?

Comment: Your definition of $\psi$ does not make sense. $\psi$ muist extend $\phi$, so $\psi(a)$ must agree with $\phi(a)$. But your definition gives $\psi(a) = \phi(a^2)$, so if $\phi(a^2)\neq\phi(a)$, you are in trouble. Take $a=2$. You can send $(2)$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ by mapping the generator $2$ to $[1]_2$, but you cannot extend it to a morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you, I see now.

Comment: Just as a quick note, for PIDs there is a simpler criterion; a module is injective iff it is divisible, and obviously $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not $2$-divisible. That can help you check quickly if you're making a mistake or not.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thanks, very useful.